# Apache Log Analysis: Unique Visitors By Date By OS

Tags: python, regex, apache, awk, grep

I need to create a one-off report on historical unique visitors (identified by IP address) and organized by date and OS from Apache access logs in the default format. Example:

```
Date OS    Count
3/1 iPhone 23
3/1 Windows 402
3/2 iPhone 32
etc..
```

I have experimented with numerous tools (Octupussy, AWStats, goaccess, appachetop) today and haven't found anything that offered the ability to break the log down this way. The OS report is found in all of those but it isn't by day, just the whole log. Anyone know of anything with that functionality?

Also:
I am considering writing a python program that will loop through the log and use regex or a system grep/awk command, but if there is a quick tool out there or if awk can do it easily I would appreciate a nudge. I have never used awk before today but it seems like it is pretty powerful and could make this simple if I had more experience.

Comment: What's the "Default Format" for an Apache Access Log?  If you're talking about Common Log Format, that doesn't hold any User Agent information...

Comment: My mistake, the format is actually: ('127.0.0.1', '-', 'frank', '10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700', 'GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0', 'http://www.example.com/start.html', 'Mozilla/4.08 [en] (Win98; I ;Nav)')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not included IP address in the sample output, I am writing answer with IP address included in the output.

A sample log line of my apache `access.log` file:

```
27.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2012:21:38:34 +0530] "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1" 301 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
```

**To get count of unique visitors per day based on the OS they are using:**

```
awk '$6 ~ /GET/ \
{ gsub("[[]", "", $4); \ 
gsub(":.*", "", $4); \
print $1,$4,$14}' access.log | \

sort -t ' ' -k 2 | \
uniq -c|awk '{print $3,$2}'|uniq -c|awk '{print $3, $2, $1}'
```

**The following answer is for unique users based on date, per IP per OS.**

One liner to get the required output from above:

```
awk '$6 ~ /GET/ \
{ gsub("[[]", "", $4); \ 
gsub(":.*", "", $4); \
print $1,$4,$14}' access.log | \

sort -t ' ' -k 2 | \
uniq -c|awk '{print $3,$2,$4,$1}'
```

**Explanation**:

The first awk line is to filter lines with `GET` request.

Second awk line is there to remove the extra right square bracket `[`.

Third line will remove time from the datetime field in apache log.

Fourth line prints the required fields.

Fifth line sorts output based on date.

Finally, use `uniq` and `awk` again to print output in the format you desire.

Output:

```
28/Oct/2012 127.0.0.1 Linux 1
```

Comment: I think OP wanted a count of distinct visitors, so where you have `uniq -c|awk '{print $3,$2,$4,$1}'`, I think `uniq | awk '{print $2,$3}' | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $3, $1}'` is more OP's speed.  IP intentionally left out.

Comment: I've given a minimalistic answer. The output given to uniq is: 

`127.0.0.1 03/Nov/2012 Linux`

I am considering the above line as a uniq visitor.

Comment: Your answer is not minimalistic, it's wrong.  You're counting the number of accesses per client IP per OS per day.  What OP wants is the number of unique client IPs per OS per Day.  You were close, but a step short.  I figured rather than yanking your answer and writing my own, I'd just point out the rather minor modification to your answer that makes it different from OP's Request.

Comment: You're still counting accesses per client IP per OS per day.  I really think that you were on the right track.  Identify Unique ClientIP/OS/Date Sets.  All I did was after that, stripped away the ClientIP information and counted the similar OS/Date pairs.  Since the clientIP must be different between sets rows with the same OS and Date, you get a count of unique IPs for each OS and Date.

Comment: I've made some changes. I was not clear about what the user was asking.

Answer (score 0):

For the combined log format, you can scan it like this:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: text = '127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326 "http://www.example.com/start.html" "Mozilla/4.08 [en] (Win98; I ;Nav)"'

In [3]: logitems = re.compile('^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \[([^\]]*)\] "([^"]*)" \d+ \d+ "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"')

In [4]: logitems.findall(text)
Out[4]: [('127.0.0.1', '-', 'frank', '10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700', 'GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0', 'http://www.example.com/start.html', 'Mozilla/4.08 [en] (Win98; I ;Nav)')]
```

Assuming that `text` contains the logfile text, using `re.findall` will produce a list of tuples that contains the information that you want.

Suppose you have this list of tuples, use a list comprehension and a set to get the unique IPs (I'm using a simple 2-tuple for demonstration purposes here):

```
In [4]: lst = [('127.0.0.1', 'foo'), ('192.168.0.1', 'bar'), ('123.022.200.023', 'baz'), ('127.0.0.1', 'double')]

In [5]: [i[0] for i in lst]
Out[5]: ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1', '123.022.200.023', '127.0.0.1']

In [6]: list(set([i[0] for i in lst]))
Out[6]: ['192.168.0.1', '123.022.200.023', '127.0.0.1']
```

For all IP addresses, you can then get all the accesses:

```
In [8]: [i for i in lst if i[0] == '127.0.0.1']
Out[8]: [('127.0.0.1', 'foo'), ('127.0.0.1', 'double')]
```

You can then filter further by date (convert it to a [`datetime.datatime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)!) and OS.